# Importing a python module and implementing it

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm practicing by creating a simple game: rock, paper, scissors. I have created two Python modules called `random_number.py` and `ro_pa_sc.py`. The first one includes the code to generate a random string and the second one implements the game itself.

This is `random_number.py`:

```
def r_p_s():
    import random
    random.choice([1, 2, 3])
    if random.choice([1, 2, 3]):
         return "r"
    if random.choice([1, 2, 3]):
         return "p"
    if random.choice([1, 2, 3]):
         return "s"
```

And this is `ro_pa_sc.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random_number
def game():
    random_number.r_p_s()
    print r_p_s()
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

However, when I try to run `ro_pa_sc.py` from the command line in Bash, I get the following error messages:

Error 1:
     `File "ro_pa_sc.py", in module "game()"`

Error 2:
     `File "ro_pa_sc.py", in game print r_p_s()`

I don't know what the errors could be, since I have checked I imported the modules and I made sure the syntax was correct... It seems that the random_number module might be the problem, but again, I don't know why.

Could anyone tell where my errors are?

Comment: You are calling the function ro_pa_sc from the random_number module, and it doesn't exist. The function you wrote is r_p_s. I can't check many more because now (I am on the mobile) but it seems to be the error.

Comment: You also need to have the ``if __name__`` outside ``game()``.

Comment: @Ivanhercaz what do you mean by "outside game()"?

Comment: could you please include complete error message?

Comment: @AnuvratParashar the error messages are complete! I omitted the lines though, but there wasn't any more info. And my doubts have already been solved.

Comment: Excuse me @Me All, I mean the ``if __name__`` has a bad indentation. But I have seen that @Vineeth gave to you a very good answer with an explanation of everything.

Comment: congratulations on getting your doubts solved. However, the lines you omitted were the ones which told what exactly the error was. IndentationError in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your files.

First, you have the `if __name__ == "__main__":` indented incorrectly. Notice the extra space in front of the `if` statement, remove that.

Second, You imported your `random_number` module into namespace but not `r_p_s()` directly. So when you're calling the `r_p_s()` directly in `print` function it's returning an error. So to fix that you can either change your print function in ro_pa_sc.py to `print random_number.r_p_s()` or add `from random_number import r_p_s` that should fix all your problems.

```
import random_number
def game():
    random_number.r_p_s()
    print random_number.r_p_s() # fix here
if __name__ == "__main__": # fix here
    game()
```

Note: 
When you're importing a module using the `import <module>` statement you can only access the functions within the module using the module's namespace. So all functions must have `<module>.function()`. To avoid adding the namespace in front of every function, you can use the `from` statement. 
`from <module> import *` where `*` means all functions in the module. But you must be careful not to cause namespace clashes when many modules share the same function names.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Would you mind explaining why I have to specify `random_number` before `print r_p_s()`? I thought it was enough by just doing `import random_number` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your `r_p_s()` function will always return `r`, because it does not compare the random number to `[1, 2, 3]`, it just chooses from the list and returns `r`. Try this:

random_number.py:

```
def r_p_s():
    import random
    rand = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
    if rand == 1:
        return "r"
    if rand == 2:
        return "p"
    if rand == 3:
        return "s"
```

ro_pa_sc.py:

```
import random_number
def game():
    print (random_number.r_p_s())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```